# Single row hotspot

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I built a Twitter clone, and the row that stores Justin Bieber’s profile (some very famous person with a lot of followers) is read incredibly often. The server that stores it seems to be overloaded. Can I buy a bigger server just for that row? By the way, it isn’t updated very often.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that Cloud Spanner does not offer different server configurations, except to increase your number of nodes.

If you don't mind reading stale data, one way to increase read throughput is to use read-only, [bounded-staleness](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/timestamp-bounds) transactions. This will ensure that your reads for these rows can be served from any replica of the split(s) that owns those rows.

If you wanted to go even further, you might consider a data modeling tradeoff that makes writes more expensive but reads cheaper. One way of doing that would be to manually shard that row (for example by creating N copies of it with different primary keys). When you want to read the row, a client can pick one to read at random. When you update it, just update all the copies atomically within a single transaction. Note that this approach is rarely used in practice, as very few workloads truly have the characteristics you are describing.

Comment: IIUC Twitter actually writes to each of your follower's feeds when you make a post. Then the hotspot rows would be people who follow lots of people who post at the same times, since all those updates would fan-in. Much less common or likely than the fan-out from Bieber.